# In TypeScript, how can I define/type a function with additional properties?

Tags: typescript

In JavaScript, I can do something like this:

```js
function hello() { console.log('Hello')}
hello.rating = "super useful"
```

So this `hello` function is now "special", since it has this additional property `rating`.

How would one declare such a function in TypeScript?

I know I could use `typeof`, but this is not what I want to use.

Here is a playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYBt1wBQEpEDeAUIokQL5FqZwB0ATgIYxhSIC8iARAM4gAOqelyKioAT0GIAGh0QTBcYCgxZREBDzbiAXLM54OAPkLkgA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [call signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures).

You can do something like this:

```
type UberFunctionObject = {
  rating: string
  (): void
}
```

The main idea is that you actually define a type for an object and then declare the `type(s)` of how that object could be called, as a function.